# Angular 7 / rxjs - After catchError happens, subscription doesn't receive more values

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Let's suppose I have this code:

```
this.service1
  .getValues()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(response => this.service2.getMoreValues(response.id)),
    catchError(err => of({}))
  )
  .subscribe(response) => {
    console.log(response)
  });
```

My problem is: if the catchError is called, new values are not coming any more to my subscription. What I would like to do is: If catchError is called, I return something like empty object and proceed normally, still expecting new values to come from my services.

Can anybody tell why after catchError been fired, the subscription doesn't work any more? Thanks.

Comment: U missed comma(,) after mergeMap

Comment: Oh sorry, this is just an example. I'm not trying to validate this code above, I'd like to understand the concept behind why after firing catchError the subscription doesn't work any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct behavior. `catchError` will subscribe to the Observable returned from its callback.

This means that if you want it to continue with emitting values from the source Observable you can just resubscribe to it.

```
import { concat } from 'rxjs';

const source = this.service1
  .getValues()
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(response => this.service2.getMoreValues(response.id)),
    catchError(err => concat(
      of({}),
      source,
    )),
  );

// Maybe this would work as well, but I didn't test it
// catchError((err, caught) => concat(
//   of({}),
//   caught,
// )),

source.subscribe(response) => {
  console.log(response)
});
```

Eventually, there's the `retry()` operator that resubscribes automatically for you but you won't be able to pass `of({})` before resubscribing.

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like to do is: If catchError is called, I return something like empty object

Try to return `of({})` in `catchError` like this:

```
this.service1
 .getValues()
 .pipe(
   mergeMap(response => this.service2.getMoreValues(response.id)),
   catchError(err => {
     return of({});
   })
 )
 .subscribe(response) => {
   console.log(response)
 });
```